# Saving and Restoring AlertDialog SetSingleChoice Option After Application Exit and Restarting

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using `SingleChoiceItems` in `ActionBar` using `DialogBuilder`. I need to save the item selected even after exiting the application then restore the saved setting when accessing the application again.

I saw many examples of shared preferences and `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` but I am quite confused. Below is the code with explanations of what I did.

**Dialog Builder**

I saved the present state of the selected option in - > selectPosition .. Then saving the `selectedPosition` in the global variable `isChecked` and setting it to the `SelectSingleChoice` arguments.

```
public void displaySortDialog(final Context context) {

    int selection = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
            Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS).getInt("Selection_key", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Sel :"+selection , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    CharSequence[] sort_options = { "Z-A", "A-Z", "Size" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sort_apps));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(sort_options, selection,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int selected_sort) {
                    /*
                     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     * sort_options[selected_sort], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     * .show(); // isChecked = restoredChecked;
                     */
                }
            });

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // saving
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS).edit()
                    .putInt("Selection_key", id ).commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choosen :"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

**Declaring and using the displaySortDialog funtion**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean result = true;
    result = menuChoice(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_Sort_By_Size: {
            displaySortDialog(getBaseContext());
            break;
        }
        case R.id.menu_Action_Search: {
            // openSearch();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Using the below code when I long press the home button or press the home button from the application the selected setting seems OK. They are selected and saved as I toast the message to make sure they are selected which means `onSaveInstanceState` is working because the toast message in `onSaveInstanceState` is displayed. But when I try to restore the settings saved through `onRestoreInstanceState()` then it doesn't work. After exiting the application the settings go back to default.

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null){ 
        isChecked = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_SORT_ITEM");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RESTORED: "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }    
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //outState.putInt(SELECTED_SORT_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(SELECTED_SORT_ITEM, isChecked);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SELECTED_SORT_ITEM+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The toast **OnSaveInstanceRestore** is shown when I press the home button from the app or long press the home button and again select the app. But after exiting the app I am unable to restore the selected settings.

If you can help me with these methods or know some other method it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference,

like:

```
    // For saving
    context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
    .edit()
    .put("Selection_key",selectedPosition)
    .commit();

    //For retrieve
    int selection = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
    .getInt("Selection_key",0); // 0 being default selection value, put whatever u want

   // int selection, Use this Selection for your UI
```

Comment: Ok so i should apply the **saving** code in the "Positive Button " i.e OK button of the Alert dialog SetSingleChoiceItem and
for retrieving the choosen setting i should use the retrieve method where i declare the SetSingleChoice dialog ???

Comment: Yes, when user presses positive button save selected value into preference, and when dialog pops up next time, just set the selection defaulting to user saved value.

Comment: Thanks for the important tips, Appreciated. sorry for action noob questions(which i am lol) But i have one problem now which is "context" and other Variables such as "PREF_NAME",  "selection" and "selectedPosition"..The problem is where should i declare these variables whehter local or global. If  i define them inside displaySortDialog() function then the variable and needed to be final and initialized otherwise error occurs. Can you please help ??

Comment: For saving use selectedPosition variable you have inside onClick of positive button.

Comment: PREF_NAME define this as string constants somewehre e.g public final static String PREF_NAME = "my_prefs";

Comment: change this method displaySortDialog() to this displaySortDialog(Context contex)

Comment: retrive selection by code suggested above in my answer as first thing inside,displaySortDialog method.

Comment: after you do builder.setSingleChoiceItems, perform builder.setSelection(selection), i guess this should be enough, let me know if its still confusing to you.

Comment: well i updated the code but i dont know what i am doing wrong. its selecting -1 as the selected value all the time which is none of the option i provided by default and then when i select any option and press ok, it still selects -1 all the time and i am not exiting the application.

Sorry brother i am kinda annoying u with this problem again and again days and weeks lol apologize for that but thank you for whatever help you are providing me with.. Really appreciated..thanks..